# nexus 7: set static IP address for non-wifi

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, networking

My desktop PC's second NIC is configured to IP address 10.0.0.2, subnet 10.0.0.0/24.  Other PCs talk to each other, when I give them similar addresses (10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4, etc.).  All these PCs plug into a NetGear 100base hub.

**How can I add a Nexus 7 tablet running Android 6.0.1 to this network?**

My USB-to-cat5 [dongle](http://plugable.com/products/usb2-otge100) successfully connects the tablet to the internet via a router.  But when I plug it into the NetGear hub instead, I see no way to specify an address like 10.0.0.5.  (Were this wifi instead of cat5, then it would be easy.)

If I replace the hub with another router (which would give the tablet a DHCP address), then the host PC gets confused because it has two 192.168 networks at once: https://superuser.com/questions/1101720/if-i-have-two-routers-how-do-computers-choose-which-to-use.

**Edit:** From google play I installed "wifi static" and, through that, set the IP address to 10.0.0.4.  But then I still couldn't see it on the 10.0.0.xxx net.  Ping from PCs to the tablet failed.  The tablet's TeamViewer  app (for remote desktop) failed to connect to PCs with "connection error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address reserve the tablet by using address reservation on router with the MAC address of the tablet.

MAC address an be found in **About Device** -> **Status**

Comment: Settings -> about tablet -> status -> (ip address, or wi-fi mac address, or any other item) is a dead end.  None of those, tapped or held, can change any setting.  I see no way to set an IP address there.  Holding an item only reports "text copied to clipboard."

Comment: Sorry, do you mean to change a setting on the tablet, or on the router?  (There is no router on the 10.0.0.0/24 net now.  But I can replace that net's hub with a router, if I must.)

Comment: on the router, theres a feature for that its called ip reservation

Comment: So the full answer is: **you can't set the IP address of a Nexus 7's wired network.**  Instead, replace the hub with a router, configured to assign DHCP addresses in the range 10.0.0.0/24.